# Building a Laravel/Meteor based web app to import a CSV from SFTP and importing HTML to broadcast emails via MAILGUN

Tags: csv, laravel, meteor, sftp, mailgun

I am considering building a Laravel based web application which simply imports a CSV file (email, name, surname, sex, age) from SFTP and import them in to the recipients table and assign a folder ID. I then wish to import a HTML file from my local machine and then do segmentation on the imported users (sex and age). I was hoping to broadcast emails (the html) via MAILGUN.

This process repeats once a day with new content (html, csv and segmentation)

My questions are:

- Is Laravel and MAILGUN suitable for this? Should I look in to METEOR?
- Are their any web apps that are open source and that does some or all of these (preferably nothing bloated)?
- Are there any libraries and or documentation you can recommend?
- How long will it take to develop such a basic app, noting that I have colleagues who are proficient in PHP and JS who will lend a hand?

Comment: Opinionated questions like this are off-topic for SO, as are questions asking for off-site resources/libraries. Read over http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask a well-received/suitable question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this type of question is too open-ended for StackOverflow. You should be asking one specific question at a time.

> How long will it take to develop such a basic app, noting that I have
>   colleagues who are proficient in PHP and JS who will lend a hand?

You should really ask your colleagues. It could take 4 hours, 4 days or 4 weeks. They are in a better position to understand the details. We have no idea of the complexity of the HTML file you wish to import nor the segmentation you wish to perform.

> Is Laravel and MAILGUN suitable for this? Should I look in to METEOR?

Without knowing more I would say yes and yes. We have been doing all new development in Meteor for the past couple years, but it depends on your developers skills and experience.

> Are there any libraries and or documentation you can recommend?

[Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/)

[This package](https://github.com/Digital-Thor/FountCouver) gets FTP file from Meteor